# What's wrong with this Collada file?

Tags: materials, import, collada

I've generated this COLLADA file: http://ix.io/1kEL

When importing to Blender, it says "Couldn't find a material by UID." 3 times, and I don't understand why. It doesn't show any other errors, but fails to import the model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say you generated this collada file, I am assuming your writing the script/program that generated it.

Within the `library_visual_scenes` you need a `node` surrounding the `instance_geometry` to define and position the object using the mesh.

```
<node id="Gem" name="Gem" type="NODE">
  <matrix sid="transform">0.92 -0.03 0.37 -0.38 0.14 0.95 -0.26 0.28 -0.34 0.29 0.89 0.64 0 0 0 1</matrix>
  <instance_geometry url="#Body__Mt_Body-mesh" name="Gem">
    <bind_material>
      <technique_common>
        <instance_material symbol="Mt_Body-material" target="#Mt_Body-material"/>
      </technique_common>
    </bind_material>
  </instance_geometry>
</node>
```

Comment: Yes, I'm writing the script that generates it. Adding a `node` gets the model to appear, but the error is still output.

Comment: I would suggest setting up the object with materials in blender and exporting from there, compare blenders export to yours. Also are the image textures in the textures folder with the dae file?

Comment: yes that is correct there is one minor modification to the script that I would make, change "transform" to "transformation"

Comment: Thanks for the idea to compare Blender's export. The textures are present. The error is still appearing, but the materials do seem to be getting imported, so I don't know what's causing it, but maybe it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Rena Just looking at an export myself, blender doesn't put the `textures` folder name in the image paths, maybe the folder name is implied.